# Java Swing with event Handling

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I am new in Java Programming and its my first time that i am developing a swing application in java Swing.
i want to implement a simple paint editor that has few buttons to add simple shapes like rectangle,square and etc.
The problem is that i cant print the shapes without actionListener but i want to use buttons to do the action for me.
I want to print or draw the shape whenever i clicked the button on the same frame that i have the buttons.

I have a DrawingPanel.java file which i got it from internet and i wrote these two other classes:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class addRect extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(50, 30, 200, 100);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    }
}

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;` 

public class test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
    }

        public JFrame frame;
        private JButton button1;
        private JButton button2;
        private JButton button3;
        private JButton button4;

    public test() {

        frame = new JFrame("Paint Program");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(350, 100));
        button1=new JButton("AddRectangle");
        button2=new JButton("AddSquare");
        button3=new JButton("AddCircle");
        button4=new JButton("Clear");

        frame.setVisible(true);
        button1.addActionListener(new VerifyListener());


        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(button1);
        frame.add(button2);
        frame.add(button3);
        frame.add(button4);
    }
    public class VerifyListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            addRect panel=new addRect();
            frame.add(panel);
            panel.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"The problem is that i cant print the shapes without actionListener but i want to use buttons to do the action for me."` -- I don't see the problem here -- simply add the necessary ActionListeners (or perhaps AbstractActions) to the buttons that need them. One issue with your code, you're not going to want to add JPanels on button push but rather have a single drawing JPanel whose state is changed by button push. Please clarify your question/problem.

Comment: when i run the code, it runs without any problem and shows all buttons.But when i click on Button1(addRectangle), it simply doesnt draw the rectangle for me.

Comment: That's because 1) you're adding the JPanel in a way that you shouldn't be doing -- it should be in the GUI from the start, and 2) you have not called revalidate and repaint on the container after adding a component, and 3) the drawing JPanel's preferred size is currently 0,0, and so that is the size that it is being added at.

Comment: Thank you , can you please change my code if its possible or write the parts that needs to be changed although you have clarified it but how i should change the size of JPanel?

Comment: see edit to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got several problems with the code above:

- Your addRect JPanel's preferred size is 0, 0, and so if and when it is added to the GUI, it will never show.
- You add a component to a container (the JFrame's contentPane) during program run, but haven't called `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container, and so the container's layout managers won't layout the new component.
- You shouldn't swap images by adding JPanels. Instead you should have one drawing JPanel, and have it change what it draws by calling public methods on it.
- Don't call `setVisible(true)` on your JFrame until **after** adding components to it, else some components might not possibly show.
- Avoid setting the size of any Swing component and instead let the components and layout managers size themselves.
- As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

---

For example in the code below, I've create several buttons and passed them anonymous ActionListeners, most of them with un-implemented code, and one of them, the listener that calls `addRectangle()`, with implemented code. In the implementation, I simply have the method call a method on the DrawingPanel object: `drawingPanel.setDrawRect(true);`. This method changes the state of the drawRect boolean held in the DrawingPanel class, and then calls `repaint()` on this JPanel. The JPanel's paintComponent method uses the boolean to decide whether it should draw a rectangle or not:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestDrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    private JButton addRectButton = new JButton("Add Rectangle");
    private JButton addSquareButton = new JButton("Add Square");
    private JButton addCircleButton = new JButton("Add Circle");
    private JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");

    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();

    public TestDrawingPanel() {
        // add ActionListeners
        addRectButton.addActionListener(evt -> addRectangle());
        addSquareButton.addActionListener(evt -> addSquare());
        addCircleButton.addActionListener(evt -> addCircle());
        clearButton.addActionListener(evt -> clear());
        JButton[] btns = { addRectButton, addSquareButton, addCircleButton, clearButton };

        // jpanel uses grid layout with one row and variable number of columns
        // and add all buttons to it
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 3, 3));
        for (JButton btn : btns) {
            buttonPanel.add(btn);
        }

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3)); // blank border
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); // add button panel to the top
        add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);  // add drawing panel to the center
    }

    private void addRectangle() {
        drawingPanel.setDrawRect(true);  // tell the drawing panel to draw the rectangle
    }

    private void addSquare() {
        // TODO: implement        
    }

    private void addCircle() {
        // TODO: implement
    }

    private void clear() {
        drawingPanel.setDrawRect(false);
        // TODO: complete
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TestDrawingPanel mainPanel = new TestDrawingPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Paint Program");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

}

// class addRect extends JPanel {
class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    // size information
    private static final int PREF_W = 300;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private boolean drawRect = false;  // use this to decide if should draw rectangle or not

    public DrawingPanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Drawing Panel"));
    }

    // allow outside classes to set the drawRect field
    public void setDrawRect(boolean drawRect) {
        this.drawRect = drawRect;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // if true, draw the rectang.e
        if (drawRect) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(50, 30, 200, 100);
        }

        // TODO: complete rest
    }

    // So that the drawing JPanel will size appropriately
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }
}
```